# Can't update (but create new) objects in CakePHP with save()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Using CakePHP 2.4.9 on a LAMP setup (Ubuntu 13.10, Apache 2, MySQL Server 5.5, PHP 5.5.3).

Trying to package a model (User) into a plugin but I have run into a strange problem:

In two different actions I use `save()` to either create or update a User. This works:

```
if ($this->request->data) {

    if ($this->User->create() && $this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Congratulations!</strong> Successfully created a new user.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Oops!</strong> Could not create a new user.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
if ($this->request->data) {

    $this->User->id = $id;

    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Congratulations!</strong> Successfully updated your user account.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'settings'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Oops!</strong> Could not update user account.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
}
```

When I try to save the latter example (the "update action") it gives me the following error:

> **Fatal Error**
>
> Error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object
>   File: /home/johan/sites/userplugin/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php
>   Line: 1412
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/fatal_error.ctp

The forms are pretty standard, I use the `FormHelper` to create form and fields. But in the update form I have a hidden field with the ID:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); ?>
```

If I remove that, the update form goes through but creates a new object! So it's like `$this->User->id = $id` doesn't do anything. I currently set `$id` "manually", so `$id = 1`...

I tried searching for similar issues but didn't find anything. One discussion mentioned the ID field, maybe it's not correctly set up? But I couldn't find any solution in regards to that.

Comment: Shouldn't Cake use `ID` instead of `id` (case sensitive)?

Comment: Don't think so. The manual says:

 // Update: id is set to a numerical value
 $this->Recipe->id = 2;
 $this->Recipe->save($this->request->data);

[Link to manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)

Comment: My mistake, ID was in some other framework. Sorry :)

Comment: The error message indicates that there might be something wrong with your model associations. Also note that there is no need to set the ID in case it's already being passed via data, and the primary key column should ideally auto-increment.

Comment: I don't have any associated models. Could it have something to do with the fact the model is a part of the plugin? Thinking I might be referencing it wrong somewhere, which makes CakePHP assume that `User` is a part of the "app space"? The id field is AI, and it doesn't matter whether I pass the id through form data or set it with $this->User->id ...

Comment: Possible that this might be related somehow, but it's pretty much impossible to tell from here. What's the `$name` and `$alias` of your `User` model, and what exactly does `$this->request->data` contain? Also show the stacktrace in case you are receiving one, if not, try to debug `Model::getColumnType()` to check from where exactly it is being called and what value is passed.

Comment: I updated the post with the data you asked about. I have debug mode '2' set up in my `core.php` but I don't get a stack trace for some reason. I'm not sure what you mean by "debugging" `Model::getColumnType`...

Comment: What I ment was insert debug output in that function to see what data is passed and what exactly happens. Something like `$e = new Exception(); debug($e->getTraceAsString()); debug(get_class($this)); debug($model); debug(func_get_args());`, that would give you a lot of valuable information that can help debugging your problem. I was kinda suspecting something alike AD7six, but as I'm usually pretty lazy I wanted to see some data first to make sure ;)

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for the code. I ran it and it turns out that `$model` was null in several of the instances of `Model::getColumnType`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ultimately found out (and should've ruled out earlier, really) was that having an array defined in my `AppModel`, for configuring the plugin, named the same as my plugin was stupid, borderline retarded perhaps.

I.e. if your plugin is called `MyPlugin`, do not define a `$myplugin` array in your AppModel.

Answer (score 1):

### There's a bad model reference

The different code permutations are not *directly* related to the problem - or may simply indicate another different problem =).

The [line of code that is failing](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.9/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1412) is this:

```
$this->{$model}->getColumnType($column);
```

Where `$this` is the User model instance. What that *probably* means is that when it fails, the object is not the class you expect to check simply do:

```
debug(get_class($this->User));
```

In your controller, it is most likely `AppModel`.

### What causes this

A typical cause of that kind of "sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't" problem is that there are some references to the model using the plugin prefix, and there are some that don't i.e.

```
<?php

App::uses('MyPluginAppModel', 'MyPlugin.Model');

class Group extends MyPluginAppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User'
        ),
        #'User' # Or like this
    )

}
```

Whereas it should be like this:

```
<?php

App::uses('MyPluginAppModel', 'MyPlugin.Model');

class Group extends MyPluginAppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'MyPlugin.User'
        ),
        #'MyPlugin.User' # Or like this
    )

}
```

What happens here is it depends upon how the relevant model is first accessed, as to what populates the `User` key in the class registry and is returned for all subsequent requests for that model reference.

To fix the problem, ensure that the model is always referenced with the correct plugin prefix (or of course no prefix if it's not a plugin model).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like you are right on the money, unfortunately I can't seem to find any class name reference directly to `User`, rather than `MyPlugin.User`, so I'm still stuck. Whats interesting is that when I debug `getColumnType()` `$model` is not set, i.e.

`'#0 /home/johan/sites/userplugin/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(1877): Model->getColumnType('id') # FAILS! $model == NULL`

but

`'#0 /home/johan/sites/userplugin/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(2563): Model->getColumnType('User.id') # WORKS! $model == 'User'`

Comment: `debug(get_class($this->User))` in my UsersController returns `'User'`. When I debug the entire `$this->User` object, it seems to be correct (the 'User' model belonging to my plugin).

Comment: I appreciate you helping out, I just updated the first post with some output and classes. I hope I got it right.

Comment: You're right in that the question is a bit all over the place right now. I will make an attempt to clean it up. Anyway. If I place the debug function inside the if statement, before `return $this->{$model}->getColumnType($column);` it does not display any stack trace! Unless I run `die;`, which actually gave me something... hmmm `$model` == `userplugin`...

Comment: AD7, I found what caused the issue and I updated the original question with the "solution". Since your answer did however pointed out some underlying issues, I marked it as "accepted". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

//Controller

```
public function edit(){ 

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

        //if you want to save on User object
         $this->User->id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];

        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        .................................
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Congratulations!</strong> Successfully updated your user account.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'settings'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('<strong>Oops!</strong> Could not update user account.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    } else {
       $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

//edit view

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User'); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('id'); 
echo $this->Form->input('first_name'); 
..
..
.  
echo $this->Form->end(__('Save')); 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry don't mean to be rude - but I don't really understand what you're saying here?

Comment: Uh... yes, I do. But I'm not sure you've understood my issue here? It's not the basics of using `save()` but rather this specific problem.

Comment: you didn't set $id value on top of your function. just updated my answer